# Unable to populate dropdown with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

http://rimi-classified.com/ad-list/west-bengal/kolkata/electronics-and-technology

The above link has a filter in the left. I am trying to use ajax to get city from state. but as the ajax is triggered the entire query is changing.

```
SELECT * FROM (`ri_ad_post`)
WHERE `state_slug` =  'west-bengal'
AND `city_slug` =  'kolkata'
AND `cat_slug` =  'pages'   
AND `expiry_date` > '2014-03-21'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

It is taking the controller name in the query (controller name is pages).

The actual query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`ri_ad_post`)
WHERE `state_slug` =  'west-bengal'
AND `city_slug` =  'kolkata'
AND `cat_slug` =  'electronics-and-technology'   
AND `expiry_date` > '2014-03-21'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

// Controller

```
public function ad_list($state,$city,$category,$sub_cat=FALSE)
{
    if($state===NULL || $city===NULL || $category===NULL)
    {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    if ($sub_cat === FALSE)
{
    $data['ad_list'] =  $this->home_model->get_adlist($state,$city,$category);
}
    $data['ad_list'] = $this->home_model->get_adlist($state,$city,$category,$sub_cat);



    $this->load->view('templates/header1', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/search', $data);
    $this->load->view('ad-list', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
public function get_cities()
{
    $state_id =  $this->input->post('state');
    echo $this->city_model->get_cities($state_id);
}
```

// home Model

```
public function get_adlist($state,$city,$category,$sub_cat=FALSE)
{
    if ($sub_cat === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->where('state_slug', $state);
        $this->db->where('city_slug', $city);
        $this->db->where('cat_slug', $category); 
        $this->db->where('expiry_date >', date("Y-m-d"));
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('ad_post');
    }

    $this->db->where('state_slug', $state);
    $this->db->where('city_slug', $city);
    $this->db->where('cat_slug', $category); 
    $this->db->where('sub_cat_slug', $sub_cat); 
    $this->db->where('expiry_date >', date("Y-m-d"));
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('ad_post');



    return $query->result_array();
    //echo $this->db->last_query();
}
```

//state model

```
class State_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
 $this -> load -> database();

}

function get_states() {
 $query = $this->db->order_by('state', 'ASC')->get('state');
 return $query->result_array();
 }
```

}

//city model

```
class City_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
 $this -> load -> database();
 //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

}
function get_cities($state){
 if($state != NULL){
    $this->db->where('state_id', $state);

    $query = $this->db->get('city');
    $cities = array();
    $html = '';
         if($query->result())
         {
            $html .= '<select id="city_id" name="city_id">';
            $html .= '<option value="">-- Select City --</option>';
            foreach ($query->result() as $city) 
            {
                $html .= '<option value="'.$city->id .'">'.$city->city.'</option>';
            }
            $html .= '</select>';
            return $html;
         }
         else
         {
            return FALSE;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        $html = '<option value="">--Select City--</option>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

}

//ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#state_id').change(function () {
                var selState = $(this).val();
                alert(selState);
                console.log(selState);
                $.ajax({   
                    url: "pages/get_cities", 
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST", 
                    data : "state="+selState, 
                    dataType: "html", 

                    success: function(data) {
                    $('#city').html(data);
                    $("#location_id").html("<option value=''>--Select location--</option>");
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please help me how to solve this issue. Please check the url I have provided and try to select a state from the filter section the problem will be more clear.

Comment: paste the code of pages.php

Comment: public function get_adlist($state,$city,$category,$sub_cat=FALSE)

Comment: sorry public function ad_list($state,$city,$category,$sub_cat=FALSE)

Comment: I have already pasted the controller functions

Comment: can you give as what is on line 66 of controllers/pages.php because its gives error on line no 66 that is Message: Undefined index: cat_name

Comment: @KaustavDey: When we select state in filter search, bottom of that bar some sql queries are showing, is it safe ?

Comment: Yes the sql query is showing as I am printing the query for your reference.

Comment: when you call the ajax is calling the whole page again not only that function i think you have to check your code again

Comment: The same code is working on http://rimi-classified.com/post-classified page and working fine

Answer (score 0):

try this in controller

```
public function get_cities()
{
    $state_id =  $this->input->post('state');
    $cities = $this->city_model->get_cities($state_id);
    echo  '<option value="">-- Select City --</option>';
    foreach($cities as $city){
      echo   '<option value="'.$city->id .'">'.$city->city.'</option>';
   }
}
```

in model

```
function get_cities($state){
  $this->db->where('state_id', $state);
  $query = $this->db->get('city');
  return $query->result();
}
```

in ajax

```
 success: function(data) { $('#city_id').html(data)}
```

Comment: there is some effect but unable to fetch the data in the city dropdown

Comment: I have commented the code which was causing error on line no 66